# Invalid Chunk Length - pull zip file from url to python

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, zip, chunked-encoding

I have successfully downloaded a zipfile from a url which contains a csv (these have been relatively small datasets). However, there is one zip file with ~2 million rows which is raising the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))
```

I can't seem to find anything on 'InvalidChunkLength'. Here's my code:

```
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

db = 'url'
r = requests.get(db)
z = ZipFile(BytesIO(r.content))

# get filename 
file = z.infolist()[0].filename

# create key, val pair
k = file[:file.find('.')]
v = pd.read_csv(z.open(file))
data[k] = v
print(data)
```

Comment: Can you download the file in other ways?

Comment: @9769953 yes I can manually upload to my db from a csv. I'd say it's to do with the large amount of data in this csv

Comment: I asked about downloading the zip file from the url. You mention uploading a CSV to your database. I'm not sure if you mean the same thing, but it sounds as if not.